# How do I output HTML form data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I hit a little bit of a wall. With my current JS how do I output the current form field results in the class="household" when the user hits "add"?

*I still want to keep the remove functionality.

I cannot edit HTML only JS. Any help gladly is appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
<ol class="household"></ol>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Age
                <input type="text" name="age">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Relationship
                <select name="rel">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <option value="self">Self</option>
                    <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                    <option value="child">Child</option>
                    <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                    <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Smoker?
                <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="add">add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JS

```
function validate(form) {

        fail = validateAge(form.age.value)
        fail += validateRel(form.rel.value)

        if (fail == "") return true
        else {
            alert(fail);
            return false
        }
    }

    function validateAge(field) {
        if (isNaN(field)) return "No age was entered. \n"
        else if (field < 1 || field > 1000)
            return "Age must be greater than 0. \n"
        return ""
    }

    function validateRel(field) {
        if (field == "") return "Please select a relationship \n"
        return ""

    }


    document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function() {
        return validate(this)

    }

    document.querySelector(".add").onclick = function() {
        createinput()
    };

    count = 0;
    function createinput() {
        field_area = document.querySelector('.household')
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = 'field' + count;
        input.name = 'field' + count;
        input.type = "text"; //Type of field - can be any valid input type like text,file,checkbox etc.
        li.appendChild(input);
        field_area.appendChild(li);
        //create the removal link
        var removalLink = document.createElement('a');
        removalLink.onclick = function() {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
        }
        var removalText = document.createTextNode('Remove Field');
        removalLink.appendChild(removalText);
        li.appendChild(removalLink);
        count++
    }
```

Comment: change the add button to `type="button"`. The default is `type="submit"`, so it's submitting the form.

Comment: @Barmar *"I cannot edit HTML only JS"* I realize the user could change this using JS, just not by simply changing the attribute in the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add` button is submitting the form. You can prevent that by calling `event.preventDefault()` in the handler function.

```
document.querySelector(".add").onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createinput()
};
```

Comment: It's working! The battle is halfway over, I need to actually display the values instead of the input field. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Displaying the values of what the user added that it is.

Comment: `document.getElementById(someID).value` will get the value of an input field.

Comment: What input do you want to display, and where do you want to display it? Add an `onchange` property to the new input field to run a function that gets `this.value` and displays it.

Comment: Hey Barmar, I have to use "name" in all these since there's no ID's :/

Comment: Then use `document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value`. It's all the same, just use `.value` on the element whose value you want.

Comment: I basically need the "add" button display all the info the user has entered in the class="household".

Comment: Give all the input fields that you're adding the same class, so you can use `document.getElementsByClassName` to loop over them and get their values.

Comment: I can't add any HTML. I can only add JS. :/

Comment: I need to get rid of the input field in the  "createinput" function and have it display the info the user entered. What's the best way for this?

Comment: Create a DIV and put the info in its `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Why is the button called **add** if it's not supposed to add more inputs to the form?